# How to apply style to element inside td - Convert html to PDF using ItexSharp

Tags: c#, html, css, itext, html-to-pdf

Currently, I am generating the pdf and sending it by mail, the problem is that the css style is not applied to the elements that are inside, of the td tags, any clue.

In the example I am using a h1 tag inside the td tag, h1 is not getting css styled.

[image]

```
  var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 80, 60);
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

   string rutaImagen = Server.MapPath("/images/LogoMOPT.png");
            

   string image = $@"<img src=""{rutaImagen}""/>";
   string name = @"<h1 style=""border: 1px solid #ff5733;"">Eddie</h1>";
            
   doc.Open();
   
   var html = $@" <table style='height: 171px; margin - left: auto; margin - right: auto;' border='1' width='676'>
                  <tbody><tr><td style='width: 225px;'>{image}</td>
                  <td style='width: 225px; text-align:center;'>2</td> 
                  <td style='width: 225px;'><h1 style='border: 1px solid #ff5733;'>Test</h1></td></tr><tr>
                  < td style='width: 225px;'>4</td> <td style='width: 225px;'>5</td> <td style='width: 225px;'>6</td></tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>";
           
          
            var sr = new StringReader(html);
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc,sr);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            doc.Close();
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Do you want to apply style on column border or on text in the column?

Comment: the text inside Tag H1, a Border

Comment: <h1> is used for text size, no border for this tag. How can you apply border on on text

Comment: Thanks, so how can apply border to text?

Comment: Any color can be applied on whole text not only text border.

Answer (score 0):

Color on whole text inside `<h1>` tag can be applied by `style` as given under. But text border can't be applied.

```
<h1 style="color: #ff5733;">Eddie</h1>
```

To apply the border on text or font, `css` properties have to be used, given as under:

```
<h1 style="text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; font-family: sans; color: white;
">Text With Border</h1>
```

**2nd Way**

It can be arranged by adding `css` class for `h1` as:

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;    
    font-family: sans; color: white;
}
```

Then no need to apply inline styling in `HTML`

```
<h1>Text With Border</h1>
```

Here is the practical example:

https://jsfiddle.net/qtjrhg72/1/

Comment: so, any way to apply the border, maybe with a div

Comment: I can't see the border